# Segue Identifier Crash Issue

Tags: ios, storyboard

Here is my Story Board and the homeSegue Identifier :

[image: Story Board .. Segue Identifier is highlighted]

Here is the code block from where i am getting back to the previous viewController :

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{


    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"homeSegue"]){
        ProductScannerViewController *product_scannerViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        product_scannerViewController.delegate=self;

    }

    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"scanSegue"]){

        [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    }

}
```

It's returning me to the ScanProductViewController. But When i am trying to click the search button again from the ScanProductViewController I am getting the following exception :

```
 2014-05-03 16:05:51.349 Spisrett[5239:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name 'Product''
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x021d71e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib
```

Please suggest me how can i return to ScanViewController without changing it's previous behaviour.

Thanks

Here is the method in which it's crashing .. Please suggest :

```
-(void) configureFetchedResultsController:(NSString *) tableType;
 {
  //NSLog(@"This is the table tyoe");
  //NSLog(tableType);

tableType=@"Product";
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription 
                               entityForName:tableType inManagedObjectContext:self.context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
//Sorted by -Ishtiak
NSString *sortColumn=@"productTitle";



//actual sort.....  decidedShortingColumn


NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                          initWithKey:sortColumn ascending:YES];


[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController = 
[[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest 
                                        managedObjectContext:self.context
                                        sectionNameKeyPath:nil 
                                               cacheName:nil];

fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
```

}

Comment: this appears to have nothing much to do with segues and everything to do with you passing "`nil`" when calling "`entityForName:`" on some core data object.

Comment: Your storyboard is set up incorrectly -- you shouldn't go back to previous controllers with segues because that creates new instance of those controllers, so you will be adding more and more controllers as you navigate back and forth. To go back, you should use unwind segues, or do it in code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is not a problem with segue.Problem is with coredata that you are searchin for entity name as product i think in this line

```
NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"product" inManagedObjectContext:appDelegateSharedObject.managedObjectContext];
```

but in your coredata file there is nor exist any Entity name as "product" so that,s problem.

Answer (score 3):

It is strange that you use push segue to popToRootViewController. It doesn't need segue to pop or back to previous view controller.